# Create a binary search function returning the index of the leftmost occurence of the desired element in the array

Tags: java, binary, binary-search

I am trying to create a binary search function and I keep getting stuck in a loop. I am confined to using such magnets. The program already gives me elements to search for. The code below creates an infinite loop.

```
  public class Student < T extends Comparable <? super T >> {
public int binarySearchIter(T[] data, T key) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = data.length - 1;
    int mid, result;
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    result = key.compareTo(data[mid]);
    while (first <= last) {
        if (result == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if (result > 0) {
            first = mid + 1;
        } else {
            last = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your confusion please? :)

Comment: Note that nobody promises you that when the `key` is less than `data[mid]`, you'll get `-1`. It can be any negative number. When that happens, you get to the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract of the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method is to return a positive integer, 0 or a negative integer depending on whether the number is greater, equal or less than the given number. Those numbers might or might not be -1, so you must not rely on that.

Therefore, you should change your while loop like this:

- If the result is negative, the key is before the middle element so we update `last` to before the middle index.
- If the result is positive, the key is after the middle element so we update `first` to after the middle index.
- If the result is zero, we just found the correct index.

Also, you are not updating the middle element once you have updated the `first` and `last` variable so you should move that code inside the while loop.

```
public static <T extends Comparable <T>> int binarySearchIter(T[] data, T key) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = data.length - 1;
    int mid, result;
    while (first <= last) {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        result = key.compareTo(data[mid]);
        if (result < 0) {
            last = mid - 1;
        } else if (result > 0) {
            first = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a binary search, while loop should start just above `mid = (first + last) / 2;`

Plus the note from Tunaki.